# Problema na codificação de Strings Qt

Tags: c++, string, qt, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou tendo um problema na codificação de strings no `Qt`. Ao mostrar alguma coisa em um `QMessageBox` ou dar um `drawText` em um `paintEvent`, minhas strings saem mal formatadas, como se não estivessem na codificação correta.

Eis como me aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do LineChart:

```
if(bTitle){
    p.setPen(titleColor);
    p.drawText((width()/2 - (getTitle().size() * 5)),40, getTitle());
}
```

sendo que getTitle é:

```
QString LineChart::getTitle(){
    return this->Title;
}
```

Uso `Debian` 7.1 64 bits.

**Alguém sabe como resolver?**

Comment: Olá Avelino, você poderia postar partes relevantes do seu código? Mostre também a saída de `file -i [nome do arquivo de código fonte]` para arquivos relevantes. O caminho mais curto para o sucesso é escrever e ler tudo com UTF-8 (veja [esse artigo](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Strings_and_encodings_in_Qt) em inglês).

Comment: Ainda nessa frente, para Strings fixas é sempre bom fixar o *encoding*: `QString str = QString::fromUtf8("Instruções");`

Comment: Olá,
Essa é a saída para meus arquivos:

avelino@amn:~/Projetos/Qt/FlappyBird$ file -i Animation.cpp 
Animation.cpp: text/x-c; charset=utf-8

Comment: Tentei utilizar:
QString str = QString::fromUtf8("texto");
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr(str)); mas ele não deixa porque o tr tem que receber um array de char ou um ponteiro.

Comment: Utilizei um trUtf8() no QMessageBox e resolveu o problema. Mas o do paintEvent ainda persiste. O que será que pode ser?

Comment: Novamente, `this->Title` está sendo setado com `fromUtf8` ou `trUtf8`?

Comment: Estava fazendo:

void LineChart::setTitle(QString Title){
    this->Title = Title;
}

Agora fiz assim, e deu certo:

void LineChart::setTitle(const char * Title){
    this->Title = QString::fromUtf8(Title);
}

Comment: Cara, muito grato pela ajuda. A documentação serviu muito. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troque o seu setTitle de:

```
void LineChart::setTitle(QString Title){
    this->Title = Title;
}
```

para:

```
void LineChart::setTitle(const char * Title){
    this->Title = QString::fromUtf8(Title);
}
```

e adicione um trUtf8 no QMessageBox, desta forma:

```
QMessageBox::information(this, trUtf8("Joaçaba"));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para que fique mais claro. O Avelino está usando uma versão do Qt anterior ao 5 (da versão 5 em diante o *encoding* UTF-8 é assumido por *default* e a função [trUtf8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject-obsolete.html) se tornou obsoleta). Recomendo a todos começando com Qt a lerem o artigo [Strings and encodings in Qt](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Strings_and_encodings_in_Qt).

Comment: Uso a versão 4.8.2. =D